# Integración de MercadoPago with Hybris

Tags: mercadopago

Estamos tratando de integrar la funcionalidad de **MercadoPago** con hybris 6.2, 
pero estamos teniendo problemas con las versioens de las dependencias.

Para **MercadoPago** estamos manejando los jar's integrados con el siguiente pom

```
    <dependency>

            <groupId>com.mercadopago/groupId
            <artifactId> sdk <artifactId>
            <version> 0.3.4< version
<dependency>
```

> java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to castjar:file:/C:/workspaceItalika/bin/hybris/bin/platform/ext/core/lib/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.classtojar:file:/C:/workspaceItalika/bin/hybris/bin/custom/italikastore/italikastorestorefront/web/webroot/WEB-INF/lib/jersey-core-1.18.1.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.class
>           at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:116)
>           at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:91)

Cuales dependencias son necesarias para actualizar?

El `pom` baja los siguientes jar's:

- activation-1.1.jar
- axis.jar
- commons-codec-1.6.jar
- commons-discovery-0.2.jar
- commons-httpclient-3.1.jar
- commons-io-2.4.jar
- commons-lang-2.6.jar
- commons-lang3-3.1.jar
- commons-logging.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- gson-2.8.0.jar
- guava-19.0.jar
- hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
- httpclient-4.2.4.jar
- httpcore-4.2.4.jar
- httpmime-4.3.3.jar
- jackson-core-asl-1.9.2.jar
- jackson-jaxrs-1.9.2.jar
- jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.2.jar
- jackson-xc-1.9.2.jar
- jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar
- jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar
- jaxrpc.jar
- jersey-apache-client-1.18.4.jar
- jersey-client-1.18.1.jar
- *jersey-core-1.18.1.jar*
- jersey-json-1.18.1.jar
- jettison-1.3.3.jar
- junit-4.12.jar
- saaj.jar
- sdk-0.3.4.jar
- stax-api-1.0.1.jar
- stax-api-1.0-2.jar
- wsdl4j.jar

Answer (score 1):

Problema resulto, era un problema de versiones. Solo se tuvo que actualizar los jar's de jersey-xxx de la versión 1.18.1 a la version 1.19.4 y ya funcionó.